# truthTable in Rstudio Error: incorrect outcome specification

Tags: r, truthtable

I was trying to do a QCA analysis of sufficeny in RStudio 4.1.3. using truthTable command. By running the code i get Error: wrong outcome specification. The outcome is written correctly. When I do an analysis of necessity with superSubset code everything works fine. Everything is coded numeric but it does not work with bivariate callibration either.

```
> ttCO21 <- truthTable( data = mydata, outcome = "CO21",
+                          conditions = "GENDG1, FDI1, GDP1",
+                          sort.by="incl, n", show.cases = TRUE, complete = TRUE)

**Error: Incorrect outcome specification.**
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and the solution was to delete any unnecessary columns (or create a new dataframe). I left only the calibrated conditions and outcome, because when I found this error, the raw data was in the same df, even if was not using it in the truthTable() command.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the 3 hours i wasted on this problem i'll share my situation and solution. I had the exact same problem. creating a new df did not help, nor did removing unnecessary colums (wouldn't make sense anyway). Completely reinstalling en reloading the QCA package did work for me. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can try "comma" instead of "dot" (in “decimal") when you import file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).